# Use celery with python 2.7

Tags: python, path, celery

It was working fine until I messed up my PATH enviroment variable. I did the following thing:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"


echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

This pretty much installed homebrew python 3 and created entire havoc ... then now celery only listens to these. I just completely uninstalled python 3. Now I'm currently facing the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/celery: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I do which python it gives me this directory:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

When I run python it's running 2.7 as expected. However celery command seems to be throwing me that error. How do I revert back to my default state?

Answer (score 1):

May be the package might not installed correctly. so, uninstall if it's installed and reinstall again with below commands.

```
pip uninstall celery
pip install celery
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Celery? Did you use pip? You may need to use whatever version of python does exist on your machine to reinstall pip, and use that pip to reinstall Celery.